# StripeSignatureVerificationError when handling stripe webhooks

Tags: express, stripe-payments, nestjs

I'm trying to handle a stripe webhook, I've used their examples for express, also tried everything found on github/stackoverflow, nothing seems to work.

[image]

[image]

After few days of trying different approaches proposed by others, I can't manage to make it working, I'm getting the same issue `StripeSignatureVerificationError` every-time, please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you testing this with Stripe-CLI? If that's the case did you change the `webhookSecret` to the generated secret in the terminal when you run the `stripe listen --forward-to`?

Comment: I managed to fix it. Actually it was the webhook secret that was wrong, not the payload which I was trying to fix. Thanks!

Comment: yeah I figured it might be that. your code looks good

Answer (score 0):

Try once with this:

```
event = this.stripeClient.webhooks.constructEvent(
    request.body,
    request.headers["stripe-signature"],
    webhookSecret
);
```

Comment: I guess the issue is with the body, not with the signature, the error is: " No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe?". 

It is the body received, I'm not parsing it so it should be exact the same one, but I still get the error. 

p.s I've also tried with passing request.headers["stripe-signature"], as expected, nothing is changed.